# Dynamics 365 - Namespaced functions not gettting called on Quick create Form onLoad

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-sales

I have a function mapped on Quick create formOnLoad event in Dynamics.

The script is :

```
var CompanyName = (function (){
  return {
    testFn : function(){
      console.log("a");
    }
  }
})({});
```

The function mapped is :  `CompanyName.testFn`

But it is unable to call.

This approach is working fine with other forms, but not for quickCreate

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed your script is valid and I've added it to a Quick Create form in my test environment.

Please ensure that:

- You've added the script's web resource to the Quick Create's form libraries
- You've registered the Form OnLoad event handler 'CompanyName.testFn' (i.e. no brackets)
- You've enabled the Event Handler

Also, you are only logging "a" to the console. I had to look twice to ensure that it was being logged because of the large amount of CRM-logging that takes place